# One MySql query to retrieve two parts ordered by Datetime?

Tags: mysql, database

I need some help to visualizing if I can do this with a query.

I have element 1 and element two.

Element one is VIP

Element two is normal not important.

ALL other commonalities are the same.

How can I select element 1 and element two from DB where I order by Date created but ALL VIPs first then normal elements?

```
table events
eventid int
eventinfo text
vip      tinyint
datecreated timestamp
```

So essetially trying to show this the vips events all first then show the rest of the events limited by 10 each page.

Comment: Very important person, so thats why they need to be first.

Comment: No, I mean what is it relative to the DB as in how can you tell that it's a VIP?

Comment: Can you show information on your table schema and data? Also any queries you are trying now that don't quite work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
ORDER BY CASE WHEN VIP = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, DateCreated DESC;
```

This will make the elements `VIP` comes first then the rest of other elements.

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/116d5/4)

Comment: Yes if VIP is a value then this would be simple. VIP is actually a column of tiny int. So Im ordering by `vip=1`

Comment: @GivenPie OK, then try `ORDER BY CASE WHEN VIP = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, DATECREATED`

Comment: Can you still limit? Thanks, I fiddled with your case. Brilliants how it works

Comment: @GivenPie - Yes, just add the `limit` clause after the `order by` clause directly.

Answer (score 0):

You should order the results by `VIP` and by `date`. It should look something like that:

```
SELECT (...) FROM (...) WHERE (...) ORDER BY date, VIP;
```

You can add also `ASC` or `DESC` to obtain ascending or descending order.